# highcharts - disable fading series on marker hover

Tags: highcharts

I have multiple series in my chart area. When I hover on a marker of any series, the other background series' fade and become more transparent. I'm trying to disable that feature and have all series with full opacity at all times.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to change the `opacity` property for a `inactive` state:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        states: {
            inactive: {
                opacity: 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wp46gdf7/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.states.inactive.opacity

Comment: First tried from CSS, but this is way better, thanks.

Comment: appreciate!!!!!