# Disabling inactive state in Highcharts styled mode

Tags: javascript, highcharts

By default, hovering over one series in a Highcharts chart fades the other series.

I'm trying to turn this effect off, but setting the `inactive` state for all series to `disabled` isn't having the expected effect:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    states: {
      inactive: {
        enabled: false
      },
    },
  },
},
```

I have *styled mode* turned on, as I'm styling the chart using CSS.

If I turn styled mode off and delete the line that imports the default Highcharts CSS file then disabling the inactive state works as expected - but turning off styled mode isn't an option.

I've created a working example (without any custom styling) in a JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/philipnye/xhmf0qae/).

Answers to other [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55595123/highcharts-disable-fading-series-on-marker-hover) don't have styled mode turned on/the default Highcharts CSS file loaded.

Is there a way of disabling inactive state when in styled mode - or do I just need to get the effect I want using CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to overwrite the default `opacity` style in `highcharts-series-inactive` CSS class:

```
.highcharts-series-inactive {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pwrb46o7/

Comment: Thanks @ppotaczek. Is the fact that the inactive option is not honoured a bug?

Comment: Hi @philipnye, No it is not. Here: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.styledMode you can read that in styled mode CSS rules are required to style the chart.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it just seems inconsistent that the `hover` state can be enabled/disabled in styled mode and yet the `inactive` state can't be - when these two states are so closely related.

Comment: That seems not to be a true. Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pwrb46o7/2/ `lineWidthPlus` property works only if styled mode is disabled. Only disabling markers is allowed.

Comment: Thanks. I don't agree though I'm afraid. If you go back to my original example (https://jsfiddle.net/philipnye/xhmf0qae), having `plotOptions.states.hover.enabled` set to `false` is having an effect. Without that line the markers are highlighted when a series is hovered over.

Comment: That is true, but it only affects the display of markers. No property in `states.hover` works. If you think that is a bug, you can report it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new/choose

Comment: For anyone who finds themselves on this page, I have [raised this as an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13518). I don't find the difference in how these two states work in styled mode intuitive, but you can read more rationale from the developers as to why it works the way that it does in the comments on that issue.